# SQL VIEW WITH JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, join, if-statement, case-statement

I have 3 tables

Node table - Nodeid, Node relationship id(NodeRelID)

Node relationship table - id, Nodeid, Node Link id

Eventstatus Tabel - id, Nodeid, Node Status.

I want to create a view where it displays each node's id and the status of the node related to it. I have done that here;

```
CREATE VIEW `view_alarm` AS 

select `node`.`NodeID` AS `NodeID`,`eventstatus`.`EventID` AS `EventID` 

from ((`node` join `node_relationship`) join `eventstatus`) 

where ((`node`.`NodeRelID` = `node_relationship`.`id`) and (`node_relationship`.`Node_LinkID` = `eventstatus`.`NodeID`));
```

Now I would like to retrieve any nodes that do not have a relationship and automatically give them a 0 in the place of the relationship status and i would like this stored in the same table so i have attempted this via a case statement in the view. Like so:

```
CREATE view `view_alarm` AS select 

`node`.`NodeID` AS `NodeID`,
(case when (`node_relationship`.`Node_LinkID` = `eventstatus`.`NodeID`) then `eventstatus`.`EventID` 
when (`node_relationship`.`Node_LinkID` <> `eventstatus`.`NodeID`) then `eventstatus`.`EventID` '0' end) AS `EventID` 

from ((`node` join `node_relationship`) join `eventstatus`) 

where (`node`.`NodeRelID` = `node_relationship`.`id`);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hm, I can't see through this just now, but do use the idiomatic `JOIN` syntax: `SELECT a.x, b.y FROM a JOIN b ON(a.a_id = b.a_id)`. Also, do you just need an outer join maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use outer joins in a recursive join

```
FROM Node n
     LEFT JOIN  Node_Relationship nr1
           ON n.key = nr.key
     LEFT JOIN  Node_Relationship nr2
           ON n.key = nr2.Key
             AND n.key IS NULL
```

Use it in your case:

```
   CASE 
      WHEN nr2.[key] IS NOT NULL THEN 0
```